# Wanting to trace family online?

Tags: research-methods, getting-started

I want to trace my family but am limited on funds.

What is the best way to trace my lineage online?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user please take the [Tour] to learn about our site.  Questions here should be quite focussed, but if you are looking for some general ideas of where to start I think this answer to a different but related question may help: http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/3801/19

Comment: Hi, Amanda, welcome to G&FH.SE! We encourage all new users to take the [tour] and read the material in the [help] to see how the site works, especially [What topics can I ask about here?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of topics should I avoid asking?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).  I've put your question on hold because it is too broad.  We can give you better answers if you can tell us a little more -- letting us know what country you are in will help us give you *better* answers.

Comment: The questions which are tagged [tag:getting-started] may help in the meantime.

Comment: Also, there is a FREE six-week Genealogy course being offered online by the University of Strathclyde which just started today on FutureLearn.  https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/genealogy  This is a great opportunity to learn HOW to study your lineage first and then worry about finding records for free or paying for record access later.  The course is suitable for absolute beginners, but there are experienced people taking the course, too -- the community is a nice mix of people just getting started and people who have been going for a while who want a refresher.